# Oauth2 issue in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Have implemented oauth2 and it works fine as long as I am using clients.inMemory in my authorization server config. When i change it to clients.jdbc, and provide the datastore, the first step of getting a oauth2 token succeeds. The second step of using that token always fails. Even though for the in memory code snippet, both steps work. so with jdbc, i am unable to reach my rest end point. I get error. The following works

```
curl -u ksclient:top_secret -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept:application/json" -d "username=mickey&password=cheese&grant_t
ype=password"
```

The result:

```
{"access_token":"4e6a6ff2-87e9-428d-9a80-13f0300a7344","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43016,"scope":"read write"}
```

Then the second step of using it fails

```
curl http://localhost:8080/oauth2/hello -H "Authorization: Bearer 4e6a6ff2-87e9-428d-9a80-13f0300a7344"
```

The error:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 4e6a6ff2-87e9-428d-9a80-13f0300a7344"}
```

What is interesting that on the mysql side the table for "oauth_client_details" does have the data whereas the table for "oauth_client_token"/"oauth_access_token" never has any records.
Here is the link to my code
https://github.com/ksachdev1/springbootlearning

Comment: can you post a part of code?

Comment: Hello emoleumassi, thanks for response. I uploaded all my code to github for your reference. Thank you for trying to help, here is the repo link
https://github.com/ksachdev1/springbootlearning